# Adding a customized keyboard in SDK 4.0

Tags: iphone

hello all i want to add my own toolbar with done button above the keyboard so i would have to customized my keyboard if i want to do that but i want to perform this task on 3.0 as well as 4.0 please guide me how could i do that

thanks in Advance

Comment: Try This [one](http://blog.devedup.com/index.php/2010/03/13/iphone-number-pad-with-a-decimal-point/). Grab the [sample code](http://blog.devedup.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/DecimalPointNumberPad-v4.zip) - study it & modify it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a `UITextView` or a `UITextField`, then use the `inputAccessoryView` attribute. You can create a view in Interface Builder and link it, or you can create the view programmatically.

Here are links to the documentation:

[inputAccessoryView - UITextView - Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html)

[inputAccessoryView - UITextField - Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITextField/inputAccessoryView)